# Show method not properly working in j query

Tags: html, jquery

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".li").click(function() {
       //If a user leaves input fields empty and tries to log in this error will be shown
        if ($("#username").val().length == "" || $("#password").val().length == "")
          {$(".demo1").html("hello");}
});
});
```

Html:

```
<span class="demo"></span>
<a href="#" target="_self" class="li" id="lin">Log in</a>
```

On Click, the text appears and suddenly disappears. I don't want the text to disappear at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's the target attribute creating the issue every click reloads the page itself which causes a refresh of the whole code because jQuery code runs once the document has finished loading because of `$(document).ready(function(){});`. The solution is to remove the target attribute or change its value.